How Cypress handles the clicks?
This is the HTML code
<div>
<li class="tabLblProperties"><a href="/pw/properties/properties_home.do">Properties</a></li>
</div>

The <a> tag is inside the <li> i.e class="tabLblProperties"
but writing the cypress code simply like this
cy.get('.tabLblProperties').click()

instead of
cy.get('.tabLblProperties a').click()

I am confused how this is working? Because the anchor tag is in the li, the clickable is a tag, not the li, right? But it is working! Please explain me how this is happening.

It's not specific to Cypress, but applies to all Javascript - events bubble.
See Event bubbling for a tutorial.
In Cypress specifically, there is no switch or option on the .click() command, but if you try .trigger('click') instead, you can turn off bubbles.
Experiment with this:
cy.get('.tabLblProperties').trigger('click', {bubbles:false})

The exact behavior depends on the implementation of the events in the app.

great answer, didn't even know you could turn bubbling off!

Please explain here like here the parent is tabLblProperties and  tag is the childer clicking event is on child <>a</> and this event is not share to parent but how here it is working

What do you mean share?
